# integrating factor of exact ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone give me a hint?

Which condition do $M(t,x)$ and $N(t,x)$ have to satisfy in order for $M(t,x) + N(t,x)x'(t) = 0$ to have an integrating factor that is a function of $tx$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu(xy)$ is an integrating factor, then

$$\mu M \; dt + \mu N \; dx =0$$

is exact.  Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \mu M = \mu M_x + t\mu' = \frac{d}{dt} \mu N = \mu N_t +x\mu'.$$

Here, $\mu'$ means the derivative with respect to $tx$.

Solve the above for $\mu'$ to get

$$\mu' = \mu\frac{N_t-M_x}{t-x}.$$

The condition you need is this last fraction $\frac{N_t-M_x}{t-x}$ to be a function of $tx$.  Then you can substitute $z=tx$ and solve the separable equation for $\mu$.